# C style arithmetic with floating point values in Bash

Tags: bash, floating-point, arithmetic-expressions

How can I have the right result from this bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(( 1/2 ))
```

I get `0` as result! So I tried to use these but without success:

```
$ echo $(( 1/2.0 ))
bash: 1/2.0 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 ")
$ echo $(( 1.0/2 ))
bash: 1.0/2 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0/2 ")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is not the right tool alone to use *floats*, you should use [bc](/questions/tagged/bc) with it :

```
bc <<< "scale=2; 1/2"
.50
```

If you need to store the result in a variable :

```
res=$(bc <<< "scale=2; 1/2")
echo $res
```

Answer (score 2):

I once stumbled on a nice piece of code, which is somewhat utilizing suggestion sputnick made, but wraps it around a `bash` function:

```
function float_eval()
{
    local stat=0
    local result=0.0
    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
        result=$(echo "scale=$float_scale; $*" | bc -q 2>/dev/null)
        stat=$?
        if [[ $stat -eq 0  &&  -z "$result" ]]; then stat=1; fi
    fi
    echo $result
    return $stat
}
```

Then, you can use it as:

```
c=$(float_eval "$a / $b")
```